# How to create transparent background color in html & css

Tags: html, css

I was creating a website which has menu and has a class topbar and has white background and i want to make it transperent not fully but still i can see a whit color i am using a dreamweaver so how do I do it

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
ul{
list-style:none;

}
li{
float:left;
font-size:20px;
padding-left:10px;

}
.background{
margin:0;
background-image:url("MWYLJ6SRDM.jpg");
background-size:1380px  auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center;

}
.topbar{
background-color:white;
height:50px;
width:100%;
color:black;
position:fixed;
z-index:1;
}

</style>
</head>
<body class="background">
<div class="topbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `rgba` to define the color: `rgba(255,255,255,0.5)`

Comment: if i want to use hex code then?

Comment: You can't, unless you change the opacity of the entire container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

The "0.5" value in example means opacity value and you can adjust transparency in there. Other values means RGB values, so you can adjust background color with them.

Comment: if i want to use hex code then?

Comment: You might want to change the clues from `0` to `255`, OP wanted white, not black :)

Comment: Clues changed from 0 to 255. I saw your comment after 4 years, sorry and thank you :)